# Time does not display when you start the timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

My timer does not show when I input a certain time, and I have checked several times what the issue could be but have no errors. I am not sure if it is related to the javascript code.

Everything else works perfectly fine, e.g. the buttons for submit, continue and stop.

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CountDown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>CountDown</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="counter"></div>
        <input type="number" id="seconds" placeholder="Seconds">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn start" id="start" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Start</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="continue" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Continue</button>
            <button class="btn stop" id="stop" value="0" onclick="check(this)">Stop</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="ok" onclick="toSubmit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.counter');
const buttonsDiv = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const secInput = document.getElementById('.seconds');

var seconds;
var remseconds;
var minuts;
var toCount = false;

function toSubmit(){
    display('start');
    remove('seconds');
    remove('ok');
    seconds = Number(secInput.value);
    counting();
}

function display(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'block';
}

function remove(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'none';
}

function check(stat){
    toCount = this.value;
    if(stat.id == "start"){
        display("stop");
        remove("start");
    }
    else if(stat.id == "stop"){
        display("continue");
        remove("stop");
    }
    else{
        display("stop");
        remove("continue");
    }
}

function count(){
    if(seconds > 0){
        if(toCount == true){
            seconds--;
            remseconds = seconds % 60;
            minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

            if(minuts < 10){
                minuts = "0" + minuts;
            }

            if(remseconds < 10){
                remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
            }

            container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
        }
    }
    else{
        container.innerHTML = "DONE!";
        buttonsDiv.style.opacity = "0";
    }
}

function counting(){
    remseconds = seconds % 60;
    minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);


    if(remseconds < 10){
        remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
    }

    container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
    setInterval(count, 1000);
}
```

This is the CSS code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left top, #0045D6, #00A9f6);
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 13vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0045F6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content #seconds{
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
}

#seconds::placeholder{
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.7rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.start{
    color: #1f0;
}

.stop{
    color: #E00;
}

#start, #stop, #continue{
    display: none;
}

.counter{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You don't have an element with id of `.seconds`.

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean by i  do not have an element with the id of .seconds?

Comment: There's no element with `id` of `.seconds` in your HTML --> `secInput` is `null`, and type error is fired in `toSubmit` function when you're trying to read the value of `null`.

Comment: It says document.getElementById('.seconds'); isnt that what the element is that you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. The HTML doesn't contain an element with id of `.seconds`.

Comment: So what should i change it too?

Comment: There seems to be an element with id of `seconds`, maybe you should try that ..?

Comment: its already there

Comment: Please take a look at your post, there is this line: `const secInput = document.getElementById('.seconds');`. `.seconds !== seconds`

Comment: @Teemu I tried to add the one you did and that did not work

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here, this begins to feel a troll post.

Comment: This code needs debugging first. Do you use a debugger? Did you step through the code? Did you inspect the variables? I checked your code, but it just has too many errors. Many of them could be fixed by a simple debugging session -- which is a must for any serious programmer.

Comment: Myne has 0 issues here is the message i receive "No problems have been detected in the workspace so far." i believe if you are copying and pasting the code then you would need to self indent it with your editor but myne works fine its just the issue with the buttons now. Because the timer is showing thanks to the answer by Abdurr but the buttons are slightly not in order, or not functioning right

Comment: VSCode or what ever editor you're using, can't detect run-time errors. You should run the code in a browser, and then open the console tab in the DevTools, there's where you check the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong: `const secInput = document.getElementById('.seconds')`; use `.` for classes. change this line as following: `const secInput = document.getElementById('seconds')`;

After Edit:
Ok. take a look at following snippet:
usage of `toCount` variable was incorrect.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.counter');
const buttonsDiv = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const secInput = document.getElementById('seconds');

var seconds;
var remseconds;
var minuts;
var toCount = false;

function toSubmit(){
    display('start');
    remove('seconds');
    remove('ok');
    seconds = Number(secInput.value);
    counting();
}

function display(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'block';
}

function remove(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'none';
}

function check(stat){
    if(stat.id == "start"){
        display("stop");
        remove("start");
        toCount = true;
    }
    else if(stat.id == "stop"){
        display("continue");
        remove("stop");
        toCount = false;
    }
    else{
        display("stop");
        remove("continue");
        toCount =true;
    }
}

function count(){
    if(seconds > 0){
        if(toCount == true){
            seconds--;
            remseconds = seconds % 60;
            minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

            if(minuts < 10){
                minuts = "0" + minuts;
            }

            if(remseconds < 10){
                remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
            }

            container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
        }
    }
    else{
        container.innerHTML = "DONE!";
        buttonsDiv.style.opacity = "0";
    }
}

function counting(){
    remseconds = seconds % 60;
    minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);


    if(remseconds < 10){
        remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
    }

    container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
    setInterval(count, 1000);
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left top, #0045D6, #00A9f6);
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 13vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0045F6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content #seconds{
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
}

#seconds::placeholder{
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.7rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.start{
    color: #1f0;
}

.stop{
    color: #E00;
}

#start, #stop, #continue{
    display: none;
}

.counter{
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>CountDown</title> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>CountDown</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="counter"></div>
        <input type="number" id="seconds" placeholder="Seconds">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn start" id="start" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Start</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="continue" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Continue</button>
            <button class="btn stop" id="stop" value="0" onclick="check(this)">Stop</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="ok" onclick="toSubmit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix which should make your code work

```
function check(stat){
    seconds = Number(document.getElementById('seconds').value);
    if(stat.id == "start"){
        display("stop");
        remove("start");
    }
    else if(stat.id == "stop"){
        display("continue");
        remove("stop");
    }
    else{
        display("stop");
        remove("continue");
    }
    counting();
}
```

- you should be reading value inside check
  Also when you are using getElementById do not use (.seconds)
  It would be document.getElementById('seconds')
- Call counting inside the check function to start counting
- In counting function make the toCount flag = true
- Make the toCount flag = false when 'DONE'

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update a few things:

```
function check(stat){
    toCount = stat.value;
    // not this.value

const secInput = document.getElementById('seconds');
// not const secInput = document.getElementById('.seconds');
```

This is enough to make it work.
Tip: if you are not sure what the value of a variable is during execution, you can try a console.log. In Firefox, Chrome you can go to developer tools - inspector, tab console to view the result.

This is wat I did:

```
function check(stat){
    toCount = this.value;
    console.log(toCount);
```

This showed me that toCount was undefined, not the value I expected and made me clear that "this" is not valid here, it's about the passed object "stat".